# msbuild: How can I exclude wildcard paths matching a regex?

Tags: regex, msbuild, wildcard

I want to include all files which match `*.c`, including in subdirectories, *except* for any file where its path (beneath the solution root) contains one or more components (directory name or filename) beginning with an underscore.

For some reason, this isn't working:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Condition="!$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch('%(Identity)', `.*[/\\]_.*`))" Include="../../src/foo/**/*.c"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

How can I do this in msbuild? I'm using msbuild 14.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sytnax you use is fine for filtering existing ItemGroups, but not while creating one (I don't immediately find where this is documented); which means this is ok:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MatchingCFiles Include="../../src/foo/**/*.c"/>
  <ClCompile Condition="!$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch('%(Identity)', `.*[/\\]_.*`))" Include="@(MatchingCFiles)"/>
</ItemGroup>
```