# Msbuild ItemGroup exclude doesn't work with wildcards

Tags: .net, msbuild, csproj, targets, proj

This Itemgroup `ItemsFromAnotherTarget` contains:

```
..\..\References\AnotherFolder\ReferencedAssembly.dll
bin\GeneratedAssembly1.dll
bin\GeneratedAssembly2.dll
somefolder\somefile.txt
somefolder\somefile.exe
bin\anexe.exe
```

The idea is to generate another item group `BinaryFiles` containing

```
bin\GeneratedAssembly1.dll
bin\GeneratedAssembly2.dll
somefolder\somefile.exe
bin\anexe.exe
```

So I have the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <BinaryFiles Include="@(ItemsFromAnotherTarget)" Condition="'%(Extension)'=='.dll' or '%(Extension)'=='.exe'" Exclude="..\..\References\AnotherFolder\ReferencedAssembly.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

So this generates the required item group. But if we replace the `Exclude` with a wild card, it doesn't work.

```
Exclude="..\..\**\References\**"
Exclude="..\..\References\**\*.dll"
Exclude="..\..\References\**\*"
None of these work.
```

The issue is the `References` folder might have multiple folders and dlls, we need to exclude the whole `References` folder. Any idea how to do the filtering using a wild card?

Comment: You could use the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498608/msbuild-how-can-i-exclude-wildcard-paths-matching-a-regex and adjust the regex so it ecludes anything matching \References\ or so. Else you'll probably have to list all files to exclude i.e. <ItemsToExclude Include="..\..\References\**\*"/> then filter the BinaryFiles groups based on that list.

Comment: Which version of msbuild are you using?

Comment: Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.1012.6693

Comment: It looks like a difference between static evaluation and handling in targets - the exclude patterns work during static evaluation ("global" item groups) but not in targets

Comment: Opened a GH issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2491

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I could get to exclude `References` folder is by Regex. It seems sort of hacky and any other suggestion is welcome.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <BinaryFiles Include="@(ItemsFromAnotherTarget)" Condition="(!$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch('%(Identity)', `.\\References\\.`))) and ('%(Extension)'=='.dll' or '%(Extension)'=='.exe')" />
</ItemGroup>
```