# MSBuild Include/Exclude doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

For some reason my files are not excluded:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Zip'">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ZipFiles Include="$(OutDir)\*.*" Exclude="*.nupkg;*.vshost.*;*.xml;*.pdb;*.snk*;Squirrel.dll;NuGet.Squirrel.dll;Splat.dll;DeltaCompressionDotNet.*;Mono.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Result files: @(ZipFiles)" />
    <Zip Files="@(ZipFiles)" WorkingDirectory="$(OutDir)" ZipFileName="../Releases/HotsApi.zip" ZipLevel="9" />
  </Target>
```

Output:

```
Result files: bin\Zip\DeltaCompressionDotNet.dll;bin\Zip\DeltaCompressionDotNet.MsDelta.dll;bin\Zip\DeltaCompressionDotNet.PatchApi.dll;bin\Zip\Heroes.ReplayParser.netstandard.dll;bin\Zip\Heroes.ReplayParser.netstandard.pdb;bin\Zip\Hotsapi.Uploader.Common.dll;bin\Zip\Hotsapi.Uploader.Common.pdb;bin\Zip\Hotsapi.Uploader.exe;bin\Zip\Hotsapi.Uploader.exe.config;bin\Zip\Hotsapi.Uploader.pdb;bin\Zip\Mono.Cecil.dll;bin\Zip\Mono.Cecil.Mdb.dll;bin\Zip\Mono.Cecil.Pdb.dll;bin\Zip\Mono.Cecil.Rocks.dll;bin\Zip\MpqTool.netstandard.dll;bin\Zip\MpqTool.netstandard.pdb;bin\Zip\Newtonsoft.Json.dll;bin\Zip\Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination.dll;bin\Zip\Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks.dll;bin\Zip\Nito.Collections.Deque.dll;bin\Zip\Nito.Disposables.dll;bin\Zip\NLog.config;bin\Zip\NLog.dll;bin\Zip\NuGet.Squirrel.dll;bin\Zip\NuGet.Squirrel.pdb;bin\Zip\SharpCompress.dll;bin\Zip\Splat.dll;bin\Zip\Splat.pdb;bin\Zip\Squirrel.dll;bin\Zip\Squirrel.pdb;bin\Zip\System.Collections.Immutable.dll
```

It looks like MSBuild ignores my `Exclude` clause. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there was an issue about a year ago where wild-cards failed to work as intended.  some used a regex expression to get a round this bug but unsure if this is still a known bug or not right now...

Comment: similar question but quite old: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45964967/msbuild-itemgroup-exclude-doesnt-work-with-wildcards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exclude patterns need to match the search pattern on a per-directory basis, so what you want is

```
Exclude="**\*.nupkg;**\*.pdb;…"
```